# We break a stick of length $1$ into $n$ parts. Find the probability that each part has a length $\ge c$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Q We break a stick of length $1$ into $n$ parts randomly. Find the probability that each part has a length $> c$.

My Approach:

Say we have $2$ parts $x$ and $1-x$, using the conditions we get $c<x<1-c$, the probability of the event is $1-2c$.

Now say we have $3$ parts $x$, $y$ and $1-x-y$, using the conditions we get $x>c$, $y>c$, $x+y<1-c$. Solving these give $c<x<1-2c \quad \& \quad c<y<1-2c $. The probability will be $(1-3c)^2$.

This makes me believe that the probability will be of the form $(1-nc)^{n-1}$. But I cannot prove this formally. Any help is appreciated.

@Greg Martin's solution (comments)

Take $n-1$ RVs say $S_1, \dots S_{n-1}$, and sort them. Now we convert the problem to
$$
S_1 > c \\
S_2-S_1 > c \Rightarrow S_2>2c \\
\text{Similarly} \,\,\, S_k > kc \\
1-S_{n-1} > c \Rightarrow S_{n-1} < 1-c
$$

On solving we get $ kc < S_k < 1 - (n-k)c $. The length of the interval is $(1-nc)$, and we have $n-1$ RVs, so we get $(1-nc)^{n-1}$. This does solve the question.

(For people looking at the comments I was modeling the parts are RVs, sampled from uniform(0,1) subject to $X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n=1$ but as pointed out I cannot condition on null events.)

Comment: This is conditioning on a null event so the answer isn’t well-defined, or at the very least, the question is under specified

Comment: I believe it's sufficient, Given X1+X2+...+Xn = 1, we need to find the P(min(X1,X2,...,Xn)>=c)

Comment: Then your belief is wrong; conditioning on null events is not well-defined. You need to specify what you mean in your question

Comment: I did edit the question @Andrew, converting it to RVs is something which I was doing and has nothing to do with the question, does the question make sense now?

Comment: No it doesn't make sense.  The event $\sum X_i=1$ is null and you are conditioning on that null event.

Comment: For those wanting to learn about the topic of these comments: [Conditioning on an event of probability zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event_of_probability_zero)

Comment: @AtomBomb: since you are apparently allowed to choose the model, you could choose $n-1$ break points $Z_1,\dots,Z_{n-1}$ independently uniformly at random from $[0,1]$, sort them as $S_1\le \cdots\le S_{n-1}$ where $\{S_1,\dots,S_{n-1}\} = \{Z_1,\dots, Z_{n-1}\} $, and consider the $n$ lengths $S_1, S_2-S_1, \dots S_{n-1}-S_{n-2}, 1-S_{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes @GregMartin, I could get that, I am unable to figure out how to solveSk-S{k-1} > c.

Comment: Well, eventually $nc > 1$, so you'll at least have to cap at $c < 1/n$ (with probability $0$ for $c \geq 1/n$).

Comment: Hi! I think @GregMartin's most recent comment is most immediately relevant: Conditioning on a null event is something to be dealt with, but in this particular case I don't see it as the most immediate problem. The more immediate problem is that the original post doesn't specify how these random variables are generated. If you think Greg's choice is suitable, you should edit it into your original post. (Your current edit isn't quite what Greg is suggesting.) Thanks!

Comment: Using Greg's notation, let $L_1 = S_1$, $L_2 = S_2 - S_1$, $\ldots$, $L_{n-1}=S_{n-1}-S_{n-2}$, and $L_n = 1-S_{n-1}$. Then it is not hard to prove that the joint distribution of $(L_1,\ldots,L_{n-1})$ is uniform over the simplex $\Delta_0$, where $$ \Delta_c := \{(l_1, \ldots, l_{n-1}) : l_1\geq c, \ldots, l_{n-1}\geq c, l_1+\cdots+l_{n-1}\leq 1-c\}.$$ Then the desired probability is $$\mathbf{P}(L_1\geq c, \ldots, L_{n-1}\geq c, L_1+\cdots+L_{n-1}\leq1-c)=\frac{\operatorname{Vol}(\Delta_c)}{\operatorname{Vol}(\Delta_0)} = \max\{0,1-nc\}^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks @SangchulLee!